# Unwanted URL redirect

Tags: dns, devops, amazon-route53, cname, http-status-code-302

Days ago, I've set up a URL 302 redirect, from subdomain.mydomain.com to target_A.com. I did it in AWS route 53 first, then removed it.

More recently, I added a CNAME record in Cloudflare from subdomain.mydomain.com to target_B.com. However, when entering subdomain.mydomain.com in my browser, I still get redirected to target_A.com ...

How is that possible? Somebody else in my team might have set up a redirect from subdomain.mydomain.com to target_A.com using a DNS web service other than AWS or Cloudflare... How do I find it and remove it?

Comment: can this help you?
https://dnschecker.org/all-dns-records-of-domain.php
Or this article
https://support.google.com/a/answer/93595?hl=en

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a page rule in Cloudflare that was the cause of my redirect (https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200172286-How-do-I-perform-URL-forwarding-or-redirects-with-CloudFlare) ...